# I want my Java program to be able to run external application in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

I want my Java program to be able to run external application in Ubuntu, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `java.lang.Runtime.exec()` family of static methods do everything you need. There is also the `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` class, which is basically a wrapper that helps you prepare calls to `exec()`. Finally, the `java.awt.Desktop` class will automatically open default system applications for various types of documents.